# Best word to convey a panther's forward crouching/slinking motion

Tags: verbs

I'm looking for the best word to convey a panther's forward crouching/slinking motion when it is sneaking up on it's victim.

By "best", I mean moving stealthily forward while crouching low and silent, ready to spring at any moment, tension held back, foreboding, graceful, poetic, beautiful, yet terrible.

I'm working on a poem in which this word is key. I once knew the word but it now escapes me. No synonyms in any thesaurus suggest the word I knew/forgot. These are the words I've already considered and rejected: avoid, bypass, conceal oneself, crawl, creep, crouch, dodge, elude, evade, glide, go furtively, go stealthily, hide, lie in wait, lurk, pad, pass quietly, prowl, pussyfoot, shirk, sidle, sidestep, skulk, slack, slide, slink, slip, slither, sly, snake, sneak, snoop, steal, and tiptoe. There are more but I tired of writing them all.

I know that I should be asking something that lends itself to being answered and not something that elicits discussion.

The other question mostly duplicates my question, except perhaps for my poetic criterion, but none of the responses to my question or the other one are the one I'm searching for. I'm afraid I've reached the point of diminishing returns.

Sorry for troubling you.

Comment: Sorry. Lurk is in the thesaurus but it's not poetic enough and it's not the one I'm "lurking" for.

Comment: The first dictionary I checked for "slink" literally used "[*a cat slinking through the grass toward its prey*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slink)" as its first example of the word.  So *slink*, itself, works. There's also, more mnemonically, *pussyfoot*.  If you want a slightly more foreboding word, consider *creep*.  And then there's *stalk*, *steal* (up on), *skulk*, *prowl*, *sneak*, etc etc. But unless you give us more details on the characteristics you *want* the word to have, I don't think we can be more helpful than an off-the-shelf thesaurus.

Comment: If talking about a feline, "to stalk up on" conveys all that meaning to me.

Comment: If you are looking for a poetic word, consider putting that in your question.  I know exactly the movement you mean, but I don't know a poetic word for it.  Glide is as poetic as I can get, but it doesn't convey the belly-down, deliberate step by step intentness of the cat.

Comment: Thanks ab2. You've come closest to that elusive word. I've taken your suggestion and fine-tuned my question.

Comment: I'd say **prowl**

Comment: "Skulking" is the word that occurs to me first.  *Skulk : to move in a stealthy or furtive manner (MW)*

Answer (score 4):

***stalking***, from [Hunting Behavior in Cats](http://pets.thenest.com/hunting-behavior-cats-7340.html)  Click on the link to see a good picture.

> You’ve seen it in your kitty – a slow move forward, then perfect
>   stillness. Her tail swishes side to side just before she pounces on
>   the hapless catnip mouse. **Stalking behavior is seen in all felines,
>   who creep up on prey until they are close enough to pounce. Hiding in
>   tall grasses, they lower themselves to the ground, advancing with
>   short, quick movements, ever patient in their approach. Then a sudden
>   spring.** Cats swish their tails just before they pounce, which prompts
>   the prey to move.  (emphasis added)

Don't be put off by "kitty".  All cats from lions to Fluffy do the same thing. It's the "lower themselves to the ground" that is the most striking part of stalking.

Answer (score 1):

Stalking would come to mind first, or for a phrase moving with stealth, prowling, but it really depends exactly what mood you want to convey.